# What is this shower head?

Tags: plumbing, shower, bathroom-fixtures

I have this shower head that I am trying to find another one of and I can't seem to find this exact type anywhere. Most of them have a flat front with little plastic orifices that let the water out, but those always clog up. This head has been serving reliably for over 20 years, so I need to know what type this is, and where I might find a suitable replacement.

Thanks!

[image: Front view]

[image: Side view]

Comment: That's the opposite of a water-saving head, so they're a bit hard to come by. Might be an [old Speakman](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1853&bih=950&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=ZFk-XMrkMePHjgTl3YnYDA&q=speakman+shower+head&oq=speakman+shower+head&gs_l=img.3.1.0j0i8i30l2j0i24l7.24815.26014..26087...0.0..0.109.842.9j1......1....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i67j0i30.Q_O1NOXIJ1w).

Comment: Personally, water saving is of no concern to me. The speakman looks similar but not quite the same from what I can tell.

Comment: Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how better to contribute here.

Comment: I feel as though this contributes fine to the rest of the community. I'm sure there are or will be people with a similar question.

Comment: Speakman is a company, not a model. And water conservation is of concern to everyone, whether you recognize it or not.

Comment: `Most of them have a flat front with little plastic orifices that let the water out, but those always clog up.` ...... get one with the orifices made out of rubber .... massaging them with your fingers unclogs them easily

Comment: I am aware that Speakman is a company, but most of the search results bring up similar looking heads that do not match mine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Years ago I purchased a shower head that at the time was called "The Big Head" and I loved the shower experience. Fast forward to today and I searched for a similar replacement. I found the same shower head but it now is a "water saving" model; same design slightly less water. I bought 2 and I think they are great. It is made by delta with a model 52650-PK and can be purchased at any store that sells Delta products . I bought mine at Home Depot using the Delta #52650-PK for around $15.00. When I built my house 21 years ago, one of the showers had that same head you are looking for, and I replaced it with the one mentioned above. I like the new one better.  my 2 cents

Comment: I actually came across the Delta head and considered it but still wanted something closer. If it works as similarly as you claim, I'll take your word for it.

Comment: The only thing that delta nozzle will not do is change the spray pattern. The lever only controls the water suooly so the supply can be reduced while you lather up , if you wish.